# No accounts connected + some other weird issues

Tags: support

I'm not sure if I should be confused or worried.

When I list my accounts (which previously were three different, including this one and Stack Overflow), I see "no other accounts" but I **do** have them. I'm not sure how to handle it...

Is it something due the recent upgrade?

I also noticed that I can't log in from my other computer. I'm entering the same credentials as I have on this one but I only get back to "sign up/recover account". What gives?!

Comment: Same here. Temporary glitch I guess. I remember this happening before.

Comment: I guess the update is still in process, and not all servers have shifted

Comment: Indeed, SE states *"Profile information is temporarily unavailable"*.

Comment: And: solved, for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the https://stackexchange.com/users/1234?tab=accounts you will find it is currently unavailable. It may be due to the updates and hardware reloactions SE is carrying out.

P.S. the id I used `(1234)` is a dummy for illustration. You can use your id

The best part I found was

[image: Flair]

**Update:**

The network profile seems to be up. And I am able to log in from different browsers(Have only one system so can do as much (: ).

Comment: Interesting flair image. You only get it if you don't have an Area 51 account, though. If you have an account with Area 51 (with at least 200 reputation), that will be the only account on your flair. ^_^

Comment: @animuson Thanks for clarifying I was just about to ask this question.