# Uploaded flair image different from what is shown in image url

Tags: support, images, flair, imgur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rep value on the new flair is not updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65889/rep-value-on-the-new-flair-is-not-updated)
>   [No accounts connected + some other weird issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147301/no-accounts-connected-some-other-weird-issues)

When I copy my flair Image URL and upload in this question using the widget, choosing the option `from the web`. I get this.

[image]

and the imgur URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHz6r.png

The same without the widget using direct link https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1366718.png.

[image: flair]

This is also the flair image that is shown in my stack exchange profile.

Is it a normal behaviour to get the flair changed during upload to imgur. It may be useful to note that I have over 200 reputation only on SO in SE.

**Update:** 
this is what i see

[image]

Comment: The two images are *exactly* the same to me.

Comment: Ah, the 2nd image is related to another issue earlier today: [No accounts connected + some other weird issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147301/no-accounts-connected-some-other-weird-issues).

Comment: @Arjan: Interesting, that explains the cached image the OP is seeing much better. This is probably a dupe of *that* issue more than what animuson linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser caches the images up to 24 hours. The image hosting service, on the other hand, does not do any such caching, so it retrieves a fresh image from the server.

It appears that there was a [glitch or update-in-progress going on with the central StackExchange.com server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147301/no-accounts-connected-some-other-weird-issues) where accounts were temporarily no longer linked today. This could have led to the image you report being cached by your browser.

It could also be that your browser for some reason is actually caching the image for even longer. You need to visit the image URL yourself and force a refresh (CTRL-F5, Shift-F5, Shift-click or Ctrl-click the reload button, Ctrl-Command-R, the exact refresh techniques differ by platform and browser).

In any case, your posting looks like this to me:

[image: spot the differences]

As you can see, there are no differences there anymore *right now*. But my browser has never before loaded your flair image, so I didn't have a cached copy of the image before I opened this post.

Comment: Ok it was the cache issue. I can't accept answer before 10 mins.

Comment: The flair generator is documented [to cache too](http://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=flair): *"please note [...] that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours"*

Comment: @Arjan: But that was not the issue here; we all saw the correct image. :-)

Comment: Still, you're writing *"The image hosting service, on the other hand, does not do any such caching"*...?

Comment: @Arjan: imgur.com, when retrieving the flair image from the given URL, will not use a local cache when retrieving the image from the server, is what I meant.

Comment: Aha, my bad! (Too bad, I already upvoted if only for showing what we were seeing `:-)`)